# Data in array not showing up in second UIPickerView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, uipickerview

I'm a newbie with IOS development so please keep this in mind with my question. I'm working on an app that will show an initial array. Based on the selection of the array, the second pickerview (shown in the next view controller) will use a dictionary and the selected option from the first pickerview to populate the second pickerview with a list of subtopics. The console is showing that all of the data is passing correctly through the process, however the data is not populating within the second pickerview. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

   @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

   @IBAction func SubjectSelected(_ sender: UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
      SubjectHandler = subSubjects[SelectedSubject]!
      print(SubjectHandler)
      print(Subjects)
   }

   //Create instances of the selected subject & the subject handler (in case SelectedSubject is not empty)
   var SelectedSubject: String = ""
   var SubjectHandler: Array<String> = []

   //Define primary values for both subjects and subSubjects//
   let Subjects: Array = ["Macroeconomics", "Microeconomics", "Financial Economics", "Game Theory",  "Econometrics", "Law Economics", "Public Sector Economics", "International Economics", "General Statistics"]

   let subSubjects = [
      "Macroeconomics":
         ["GDP", "Accounting Methods", "Labor Market", "DMP Job Search Model", "Keynesian Economics", "Sticky-Price Model", "Elasitcity", "Supply and Demand"],

      "Microeconomics":
         ["Elasticity", "Consumer Theory", "Preference Curves", "Competitive Models", "Scarcity"],

      "Financial Economics":
         ["Interest", "Dividends Returns", "Return & Expected Return"],

      "Game Theory":
         ["Nash Equilibrium", "Dominant Strategies", "Iterated Games", "Backwards Induction", "Extensive Form Games"],

      "Econometrics":
         ["Capital Asset Pricing Model", "Regressional Analysis", "Modeling Rules", "Central Limit Theorem", "Probablitiy & Distribution","Heteroscedasticity", "Weighted Least Squares", "Sampling Distributions"],

      "Law Economics":
         ["Externalities", "Damages Calculations", "Property Rights Ownership", "Claims", "Ownership Principles"],

      "Public Sector Economics": ["Valuations", "Tax Income Calculations", "Budget Analysis"], "International Economics": ["Taxing Methods", "Importing and Exporting", "Currency Exchange Rates", "Tarrifs", "GDP", "Product Purchase Parity"],

      "General Statistics":
         ["Z-Scores", "Summary Statistics", "One-Tailed Hypothesis Testing", "Two-Tailed Hypothesis Testing", "Confidence Intervals", "Upper and Lower Bounds"]
   ]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      pickerView.delegate = self
      pickerView.dataSource = self
      if pickerView.tag == 2 {
         pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
      }
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
      return 1
   }
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
      if pickerView.tag == 1 {
         return Subjects.count
      }
      else {
         return SubjectHandler.count
      }
   }
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
      if pickerView.tag == 1 {
         return Subjects[row]
      }
      else {
         return SubjectHandler[row]
      }
   }
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {
      SelectedSubject = Subjects[row]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said, you use a separate viewController object at the second screen. When it gets loaded it will have an empty `SubjectHandler` array.

You sould pass the array between viewControllers. See [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-passing-data-between-controllers-in-swift--cms-27151)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize you needed separate viewControllers for each screen!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and let you know that your answer helped me solve the issue....I was banging my head on a wall for days trying to figure that one out! Thank you once again

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your app!